# Read a multiple data typed .dat file into a python array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Looking to get a faster way to parse the following .dat file, into a list or a numpy array.
Tried multiple configurations of `np.genfromtxt(), np.loadtxt(),` also just a `csv.reader()`, from a csv module.

The issue/ challenge being - One, the delimiter is `","` in first four lines and `" "` (space) after that. Second, the data is also a combination of strings/ floats. I am mainly looking to read the 3rd line (I, J values), and the data from 5th line to an array.

```
TITLE = "B0001"
VARIABLES = "x [mm]", "y [mm]", "Intensity [counts]", "isValid"
ZONE T="Frame 0", I=1930, J=1798, F=POINT
STRANDID=1, SOLUTIONTIME=0.100904755
-123.047997 130.550003 0 0
-122.915267 130.550003 0 0
-122.782537 130.550003 0 0
-122.649806 130.550003 0 0
-122.517076 130.550003 0 0
-122.384346 130.550003 0 0
```

Comment: Just do regular Python line read, with the necessary string splits and parsing.  `genfromtxt` is overkill, and intended for the section with neat columns, not the header lines.  Also `genfromtxt` uses Python line reads; it does not use "fast" compiled code.  `pandas.csv_read` has a faster mode, but it too is intended for the neat columns (the CSV portion).

Comment: Start by reading the first two lines to throw them away, read third line and process it with Python string functionality (e. g. with regular expressions). Read fourth line and throw it away and hand over the file object to a csv reading function of pandas, numpy or Python's standard library.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Could you write a working example. I understand what you mean here, but the idea of giving the file object to csv reader, after reading fourth line, I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: Show in this or better in a new question the code you tried and explain what fails. If there is an error message show it completely in the question, too.